# Unable to retrieve Parcel implemented class from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parcel, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a class called `Weekly Result` which implements Parcel interface. I am having a problem retrieving the parcel object when I pass it to another activity.

This is my `weeklyResult` class:

```
public class WeeklyTopicResult implements Parcelable {

public String ID;
public MultiLingual Title = new MultiLingual();
public MultiLingual Text = new MultiLingual();
public String ImageUrl;
public String PublishOn;
public Bitmap ImageSource;

public WeeklyTopicResult(Parcel in) {
    // Reads the obj value
    ReadFromParcel(in);

}

public WeeklyTopicResult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("WeekData", "WriteToParcel..." + flags);
    dest.writeString(ID);
    dest.writeString(ImageUrl);
    dest.writeString(PublishOn);
    dest.writeParcelable(Title, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(Text, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(ImageSource, flags);

}

public void ReadFromParcel(Parcel obj) {
    Log.v("WeeklyClaas",
            "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");
    ID = obj.readString();
    Title = (MultiLingual) obj.readParcelable(MultiLingual.class
            .getClassLoader());
    Text = (MultiLingual) obj.readParcelable(MultiLingual.class
            .getClassLoader());
    ImageUrl = obj.readString();
    PublishOn = obj.readString();
    ImageSource = (Bitmap) obj
            .readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());

}

public class WeeklyTopicResultParcelCreater implements
        Parcelable.Creator<WeeklyTopicResult> {

    @Override
    public WeeklyTopicResult createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new WeeklyTopicResult(source);
    }

    @Override
    public WeeklyTopicResult[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new WeeklyTopicResult[size];
    }
}
}
```

This is my `Multilinqual` class:

```
public class MultiLingual implements Parcelable {

public String ArbicValue;

public String EnglishValue;

public MultiLingual(Parcel in) {
    ReadFromParcel(in);
}

public MultiLingual() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(ArbicValue);
    dest.writeString(EnglishValue);

}

private void ReadFromParcel(Parcel Obj) {

    ArbicValue = Obj.readString();
    EnglishValue = Obj.readString();
}

public class MyMultiLingualParcelCreator implements
        Parcelable.Creator<MultiLingual> {

    @Override
    public MultiLingual createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MultiLingual(source);
    }

    @Override
    public MultiLingual[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new MultiLingual[size];
    }

}
}
```

And here is where I am sending the object which intent:

```
public void GoToWeeklyTopic(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(HomeActivity.this, Topic_of_the_week.class);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    WeeklyTopicResult w = weeks;

    // Puts the weeklyresult parcel class into bundle
    b.putParcelable("WeeklyContent", w);

    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here's the activity class where I am trying to receive my parcel object:

```
ImageView weekImg;
TextView title;
TextView ContentText;
WeeklyTopicResult week= new WeeklyTopicResult();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic_of_the_week);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            //Here I am receiving an error
    week =extras.getParcelable("WeeklyContent");


    weekImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_MainTitle);
    ContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_page_content_topicweek);

    title.setText(week.Title.EnglishValue);
    ContentText.setText(week.Text.EnglishValue);
    weekImg.setImageBitmap(week.ImageSource);
    // String FullPath = RetrieveData_Preference("WeeklyTopicUrl") + Url;
    // getImage(FullPath);

}
```

I even tried to cast the object back but still I am having an error. Logcat error showed me this error but I already implemented a creater class for weeklyresult

LogCat error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>
> ComponentInfo{com.example.laysapp/com.example.laysapp.AdminPage.Topic_of_the_week}:
>   android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.example.laysapp.ParsingLogic.WeeklyTopicResult
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1231):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a 
>           Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class 
>           com.example.laysapp.ParsingLogic.WeeklyTopicResult
>           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2086)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
>           at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
>           at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
>           at com.example.laysapp.AdminPage.Topic_of_the_week.onCreate(
>               Topic_of_the_week.java:40)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>           ... 11 more

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface.

So add this field to your `MultiLingual` class:

```
public static final MyMultiLingualParcelCreator CREATOR = new MyMultiLingualParcelCreator();
```

Comment: ... which could have been easily figured out by looking at the stack trace: "android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR...".

Comment: The same applies to the `WeeklyTopicResult` class. It also must have a static `CREATOR` field initialized to `new WeeklyTopicResultParcelCreater()`

Comment: Henry can you provide me some sample as i did create a static variable in both classes its keep giving me as error

Answer (score 0):

You always have to read in the same order that you write:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("WeekData", "WriteToParcel..." + flags);
    dest.writeString(ID);
    dest.writeString(ImageUrl);
    dest.writeString(PublishOn);
    dest.writeParcelable(Title, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(Text, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(ImageSource, flags);

}

public void ReadFromParcel(Parcel obj) {
    Log.v("WeeklyClaas",
            "ParcelData(Parcel source): time to put back parcel data");
    ID = obj.readString();
    //these were lower
    ImageUrl = obj.readString();
    PublishOn = obj.readString();
    Title = (MultiLingual) obj.readParcelable(MultiLingual.class
            .getClassLoader());
    Text = (MultiLingual) obj.readParcelable(MultiLingual.class
            .getClassLoader());
    ImageSource = (Bitmap) obj
            .readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

Comment: i rearranged the code like you suggested still i am can't retrieve the parcel object.